# Image Registration of Scanned Text Forms

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-registration

We print 500 bubble surveys, get them back, and scan them in a giant batch giving us 500 PNG images.

Each image has a slight variations in alignment, but identical size and resolution.  We need to register the images so they're all perfectly aligned.  (With the next step being semi-automated scoring of the bubbles).

If these were 3D-MRI images, I could accomplish this with a single command line utility;  But I'm not seeing any such tool for aligning scanned text documents.

I've played around with opencv as described in  [Image Alignment (Feature Based) using OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/), and it produces dynamite results when it works, but it often fails spectacularly.   That approach is looking for documents hidden within natural scenes, a much harder problem than our case where the images are just rotated and translated in 2D, not 3.

I've also explored [imreg_dft](https://pypi.org/project/imreg_dft/), which runs consistently but does a very poor job -- presumably the dft approach is better on photographs than text documents.

Does a solution for Image Registration of Scanned Forms already exist?   If not, what's the correct approach? Opencv, imreg_dft, or something else?

Similar prior question:  [How to find blank field on scanned document image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548309/how-to-find-blank-field-on-scanned-document-image)

Comment: if you can afford to provide control points (at 4 corners of the actual image border), then you could try doing a affine transformation like https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/

Comment: Printing control points on the documents would have definitely been a great idea, but sadly surveys were printed, filled out, and scanned before I was involved -- can't add 'em now.

Comment: Can you add a (blank) example image?

Comment: I can't, but fortunately the publisher already has!  Images are here:

https://www.amazon.com/MacArthur-Bates-Communicative-Development-Inventories-Sentences/dp/1557668892

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51UQs%2Bp8ByL._SX375_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg

Comment: So the image has these standardized solid black rectangles that are potentially useful.  The bubbles themselves are similarly standardized.  I'm just surprised there isn't a simple solution for any text form, regardless of its content.  That seems so much easier that registering MRIs

Comment: Have you tried cv2.findTransformECC and then cv2.warpAffine as opposed to ORB feature matching?

Comment: I've tried findTransformECC and WarpAffine, but the results are comparable to img_dft -- it DOES run consistently, which is more than I can say for the Orb+Matcher+FindHomography solution.   But the  [resulting image](https://imgur.com/a/hFPWwpf) is pretty badly misaligned.  In some cases the bubbles don't even overlap across the forms.      (Note:  the large white regions in the image are just my redactions)

Answer (score 2):

What you can try is using the red outline of the answer boxes to create a mask where you can select the outline. I create a sample below. You can also remove the blue letters by creating a mask for the letters, inverting it, then apply it as a mask. I didn't do that, because he image of the publisher is low-res, and it caused issues. I expect your scans to perform better.

When you have the contours of the boxes you can transform/compare them individually (as the boxes have different sizes). Or you can use the biggest contour to create a transform for the entire document.

You can then use [minAreaRect](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#b-rotated-rectangle) to find the cornerpoints of the contours. Threshold the [contourArea](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-area) to exclude noise / non answer area's.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# load image
img = cv2.imread('Untitled.png')
# convert to hsv colorspace
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of image bachground in HSV
lower_val = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_val = np.array([179,255,237])

# Threshold the HSV image 
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

# find external contours in the mask
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contours
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),3)

# display image
cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```